# Retrofit: no body on HTTP DELETE response only for cellular networks

Tags: android, retrofit, http-delete

I have HTTP DELETE API endpoint with some body in response.

If I try to send that request over wi-fi network, I get complete response: HTTP headers and response body. After switching off the wi-fi and sending the request over cellular network, I get response consisting only of HTTP headers and with no body.

This behavior is the same on HTTPUrlConnection and OkHttp transport layer. Retrofit 1.6.1, Android 5.1.1 on Nexus 5.

#### Here is retrofit interface:

```
public interface VoteInterface {
    @DELETE("/product/{product_id}/{vote_type}")
    VoteResponse unvote(
            @Query("access_token") String token,
            @Path("product_id") String productId,
            @Path("vote_type") String voteType
    );
}
```

#### Initialization:

```
// ... snip ...
RestAdapter.Builder builder = super.createRestAdapterBuilder();
builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
return builder;
```

The rest of work is done by Robospice code, I guess it is not so interesting to inspect the issue.

#### Here is the part of Retrofit logs:

```
09-10 01:00:33.233  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP DELETE http://.../product/55ba5fe611ce3907288b4567/unlike?access_token=DaoHrTqvuAot1qDsRbbVvDxeuQVBnSMO0iLrKlEm
09-10 01:00:33.233  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/c... D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://.../product/55ba5fe611ce3907288b4567/unlike?access_token=DaoHrTqvuAot1qDsRbbVvDxeuQVBnSMO0iLrKlEm (160ms)
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Connection: keep-alive
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 22:00:41 GMT
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1441836033393
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1441836033243
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Server: nginx
09-10 01:00:33.393  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
09-10 01:00:33.394  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ Vary: Accept-Encoding
09-10 01:00:33.394  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26-1~dotdeb+7.4
09-10 01:00:33.394  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://.../product/55ba5fe611ce3907288b4567/unlike?access_token=DaoHrTqvuAot1qDsRbbVvDxeuQVBnSMO0iLrKlEm
09-10 01:00:33.398  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ java.io.EOFException
            at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:64)
            at okio.GzipSource.consumeHeader(GzipSource.java:114)
            at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:73)
            at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
            at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
            at retrofit.Utils.streamToBytes(Utils.java:43)
            at retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary(Utils.java:81)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter.logAndReplaceResponse(RestAdapter.java:470)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter.access$500(RestAdapter.java:109)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:333)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
            at $Proxy12.unvote(Unknown Source)
            at ....VoteRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(VoteRequest.java:35)
            at ....VoteRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(VoteRequest.java:5)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-10 01:00:33.398  27443-27509/... D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

`

Comment: Can you post code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: it is http or https? (i would not be surprised if some network provider considered that responses from a DELETE did not need to be transmitted)

Comment: I use http. What you mean about 'network provider' - isp or underlying service? The behavior is the different on the same uri with different transports.